# How to make a method or property global in all components

Tags: angular

I'm creating a new angular project, and I want to create a button that toggles between two themes to change some styles, this button in the one of component and I need to do changes in all components, what's the best way to do that?

note: I'm a beginner

I tried to use Ng class to change styles but it only works in the same component and didn't work in others "and I think it's a bad way"

Comment: a theme should be done via css pretty much exclusively. you just apply one "theme" class to the app container and that selector should change all of the app styles it needs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CSS is not really dynamic, you will either have to change theme by replacing everything inline or create a new theme file.

I would choose the latter. You can then set a class on the App host to overwrite default styles i.e.

```
@HostBinding('class') themeClass: string;
```

You can have a button click event to either [EventEmit](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) to App from child component or use a [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4) to share the event.

```
<button (click)="onChangeTheme('<class name string>')"></button>
```

I don't know your structure, so I can't say what's best.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a directive i think

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

You can add it to any HTML element and it will receive the directive logic